# Is it possible to exploit XSS inside User-Agent header?

Tags: web-application, xss

I've found an xss bug inside user-agent header on one popular buy/sell site , and after reporting it to them , they answered that it is not dangerous as it can not be exploited without user interaction(changing user-agent header manually).
So I wanted to ask , is there any way to send user-agent and request that same page with spoofed user-agent. Can any web programming language do that?
Thanks

Comment: Which bug? Be more detailed.

Comment: There is a cross site scripting on mobile version of that site , it is showing my user-agent inside source code.So when I use temper data I can change user-agent to "><script>alert(0)</script> and crate javscript alert. But how to request for that page with spoofed user-agent without need to use temper data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible for an attacker to control the user-agent in a cross site request.   Usually XSS payloads are simple `<form>` elements with javascript to automatically call `.submit()` or an `<iframe>`.

It is possible to exploit XSS via *some* HTTP headers using Flash. However, flash has a [blacklist of http headers](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/actionscript-error-send-action-contains.html).  The user-agent was blacklisted in version 9.0.28,  so once upon a time you could exploit user-agent based XSS.  I wrote the [CSRF-Request-Builder](https://github.com/TheRook/CSRF-Request-Builder) to take advantage of Flash's control over HTTP headers.

Comment: Thanks , seems like there is no way , now . I've downloaded the tool and downgraded my flash player , just to test it.It works great.Thanks