# Why can't I send raw HTTP requests with arbitrary headers from a web application?

Tags: javascript, websocket, telnet

I am trying to write a script to test a [Suricata](https://suricata-ids.org/) network signature.  To do this I need to simulate the same user agent as the malware.  I tried the following.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(request) {
        request.setRequestHeader("User-Agent","XAgent/1.");
    }
});
$.ajax({
    url: "localhost",
    type: "GET"
});
```

But I got the error `Refused to set unsafe header "User-Agent"`.

I have also tried `WebSocket` and `socket.io.js` but each of those do not allow me to actually send a raw HTTP request.

What I want is a tool like `telnet` in the browser so I can just send the raw HTTP request and define all the fields, but this seems not possible. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Your browser should have a way of spoofing a user agent string. Google that.  If that fails try netcat.

Comment: yea, I know I can spoof the user agent with a plugin, but I need to create a test page for people that are not technical to use.  I can't use nc because it is also not very easy to use, even with a script it isn't installed on every computer.

Comment: I'm not sure you're going to have any luck with that unless you're using some sort of ancient browser.  I assume you need this to come from multiple IP addresses, or will a single one work just fine?

Comment: Browsers attempt to prevent you from doing mischievous things such as changing the user agent to something other than what the browser wants it to be.  Just like they prevent you from making unauthorized cross origin requests.  I'm not sure why you are surprised at that.  If you go outside the browser to pretty much any other tool that can make web requests, then you can muck with them to your heart's content, but not from within the browser's controlled environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I got the error `Refused to set unsafe header "User-Agent"`

Browser behavior varies here. Firefox allows unprivileged web applications to issue a custom `User-Agent` header to the same domain (or to other origins via [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)), but Google Chrome doesn't.

`User-Agent` is not in Mozilla's list of [forbidden headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name):

> **Note:** The User-Agent header is no longer forbidden, [as per spec](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#terminology-headers) — see forbidden header name list (this was implemented in Firefox 43,) so can now be set in a Fetch [Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers) object, via XHR [setRequestHeader()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#setRequestHeader%28%29), etc.

But you will never be able to send the header cross-domain without permission. That's also why XSS flaws based on altered user-agent strings [are usually not exploitable](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/31835/95381).

Beyond that, an unprivileged web application can't issue actual "raw HTTP requests" for obvious security reasons. Even if you write a browser plugin, chances are that you have to go through the respective higher-level APIs and can't *entirely* control HTTP requests on a byte level, as you could using `netcat`.

Comment: Nice, the comment about FireFox did it for me.  I just told my users the code only works on FireFox